# Вывод чисел с пробелом в качестве разделителя разрядов в Pascal ABC

Tags: pascalabc.net, формат

Осваиваем с ребенком Pascal ABC.
Уважаемое сообщество.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить вывод чисел с пробелом в качестве разделителя разрядов.
То есть, число 123456789 вывести так: 123 456 789

Answer (score 2):

WritelnFormat со спецификатором формата N0

```
WritelnFormat('{0:N0}', 123456789)
```

Используется системный разделитель групп разрядов, установленный в Windows. Если это не пробел, в дотнете нужно установить `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator`. Есть ли такая возможность в ABC -  не знаю.